# Dynamically changing costs in custom pc builder with checked inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

First, [please take a look at my fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/HpEJf/4/)

I'm trying to figure out a clean way of making the price next to each item change when any item is selected (in that group, you can image that there will be graphics cards etc in a different section which also will need the same functionality).

If its positive I need the class to be `.positive` and vice versa, and if the item is selected `(+0)` then the price difference wont be displayed.

This will also be used on checkbox's.

[Non-working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/FRGJE/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to compare each selected item with items having the same name.  In the `.each()` loop in `CalculatePrice()`, pass the checked item to this function:

```
function CalculateDiffs(item) {
    var selectedPrice = +item.data("price");
    item.siblings(".item_price").text("");
    $(".calculation-item[name='"+item.attr("name")+"']").not(item).each(function(){
        var price = +$(this).data("price");
        var diff = (price-selectedPrice).toFixed(2);
        if (diff >= 0) {
            diff = "+"+diff;
        }
        $(this).siblings(".item_price").toggleClass("negative", diff < 0).text(diff);
    });
}
```

As for checkboxes, the above function will take care of hiding the price when it is checked.  To display the prices for unchecked checkboxes:

```
$(".calculation-item:checkbox:not(:checked)").each(function(){
    $(this).siblings(".item_price").text("+"+$(this).data("price"));
});
```

Or, if you want to display the price of a checked checkbox as negative, use this instead:

```
$(".calculation-item:checkbox").each(function(){
    var diff = (this.checked ? "-" : "+") + $(this).data("price");
    $(this).siblings(".item_price").toggleClass("negative",this.checked).text(diff);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/HpEJf/8/

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's pretty straight forward, all you'll need to do is calculate the difference between the selected price and the price of all the options in the list. Eg, something like this:

```
$(".calculation-item").each(function(index) {
    var my_cost = base_price + $(this).data("price");
    var difference = Math.round(my_cost - base_cost);
});
```

I've created a working jsFiddle for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/HpEJf/6/. You'll need to implement decimal rounding etc but this should put you on the right track :)

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you want to display the cost difference from the previously selected radio button and the currently selected radio button.

To do that you need to keep track of the previously selected button. The only way I know of to do that is to set a variable outside the clickhandler scope to keep track of it and update the element in the clickhandler.

The rest is fairly straightforward. I updated your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FRGJE/4/) with an example of how to do it. The relevant code is below:

Adding at top of script:

```
//global for last checked/selected radio
var lastSelection = $(".calculation-item:checked");
//clear existing price diffs set by markup
$('span.processor_price').text('');
```

Added another function:

```
function priceDifference(oldPrice, newPrice) {
    var difference = {
        'cssClass': '',
        'inCost': '0'
    };
    var fixedDiff = '';
    var diff = newPrice - oldPrice;
    diff = Math.ceil(Math.abs(diff * 100)) / 100;
    fixedDiff = diff.toString();
    if (newPrice < oldPrice) {
        difference.cssClass = 'negative';
        difference.inCost = '-' + fixedDiff;
    } else if (newPrice > oldPrice) {
        difference.cssClass = 'positive';
        difference.inCost = '+' + fixedDiff;
    }
    /* else {
    * must be the same, no reason for this block
    * as the default empty string will suffice
    * as will the cost difference of 0
    }*/
    return difference;
}
```

And changed your click handler to:

```
$(".calculation-item").click(function() {
    var difference = {};
    if (lastSelection) {
        //get difference
        difference = priceDifference($(lastSelection).data("price"), $(this).data("price"));
        //change class
        $(this).siblings('span.processor_price').addClass(difference.cssClass).text(difference.inCost);
        $(lastSelection).siblings('span.processor_price').removeClass('positive').removeClass('negative').text('');
        if (lastSelection !== this) {
            lastSelection = this;
        }
    } else {
        lastSelection = this;
    }
    CalculatePrice();
});​
```